# SSRS How to do a cross database join without hardcoding the database name in the report query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, datasource

I have an SSRS report on that connects to two databases in its query.

```
SELECT table
FROM MainDB1.DBO.Table AS table1
JOIN MainDB2.DBO.Table AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

It is using an SSRS data-source to connect to its server. When I want to edit the report i have to do so on a separate server, this server has the same databases but they are named diffently.

I have to manually edit the query to look like this in order for me to be able to change the report

```
SELECT table
FROM DevDB1.DBO.Table AS table1
JOIN DevDB2.DBO.Table AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Each report server datasource is the same name and referenced in the report.

Is there a way in the dataset to join these two databases? Or does anyone have their own way of handling this problem? It would make this process way more efficient.

Thanks

Comment: *When I want to edit the report i have to do so on a separate server?* Why? Could you not edit the report on the production server? Also, would it not be much more useful if your development server and production server used the same database names? Surely this has caused more issues than just developing reports? Finally, is `Ctrl+H` to find and replace `MainDB1` with `DevDB1`, and `MainDB2` with `DevDB2` in your query really that laborious?

Comment: The cleanest way to handle this is to have consistent database, schema, and object names between your environments.  Anything else will cause all kinds of problems, and provide almost no benefit... so why do it?  If this isn't your decision to make, a potential work-around would be to to create a `SYNONYM` for each reference object from `DB2` in `DB1`... then re-write the query to use the synonyms so that no cross-database references are needed... and then your query could use just the 2-part name, and let the connection for each environmetn determine whether or not it is `Dev` or `Main`.

Comment: It's possible to have consistent database, schema and object names sure, but linked servers take on the server name which is rarely (I hope) the same between production, test and development environments. The `SYNONYM` approach is the best one I've found as it allows us to test deployment and migration scripts and move them between environments without having to edit them. Just make separate scripts to create the synonyms for each environment.

Comment: @JC. Linked Servers don't necessarily need to take on the server name... using `sp_addlinkedserver`, the `@datasrc` parameter is the server name, but the `@server` parameter can be called whatever you want... which is how you reference the linked server in code.  Using these parameters, your linked servers can have consistent names between environments but point to totally different servers in each location.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow Michael Fredrickson's advice of using consistent naming across your environments and using server aliases for your linked servers to maintain that consistency.

Having said that, given the way your environment is I would suggest having an expression-based Sql statement that uses hidden parameters to achieve what you want. So set up two hidden string parameters:

`@Db1` defaults to `DevDB1` and `@Db2` defaults to `DevDb2`

Now use the following expression for your Sql statement:

```
="SELECT table "
&"FROM " + Parameters!Db1.Value + ".DBO.Table AS table1 "
&"JOIN " + Parameters!Db2.Value + ".DBO.Table AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID"
```

This builds the correct Sql from the values of the database parameters.

Once you deploy to the Reporting Services server, go onto the server and edit the parameters:

`@Db1` defaults to `MainDB1` and `@Db2` defaults to `MainDB2`

When the report is subsequently re-deployed, the local parameter default values do not overwrite the default values that have been changed on the server, so these server values will remain as you set them.

When people run the report they won't see the parameters as they are hidden. They simply have different settings locally for development and on the server for production.